# Print a file in one single row ksh

Tags: shell, row, ksh, display

I have the **file DATA**, and within it there is:

```
Name                   | Karlstrom|

Description            | New_Server|

Type                   | UNIX OS|

Formula                | y=kx+j |

Severity                | Critical|
```

I need to know how to display the data like this:

```
Name| Karlstrom|Description| New_Server|Type UNIX OS|Formula| y=kx+j|Severity| Critical|
```

**USING KORN SHELL | KSH**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements do not explain all cases, but the following code will handle your example input:

```
sed -e 's/ *|/|/' DATA | tr -d "\n"; echo
# Output:
Name| Karlstrom|Description| New_Server|Type| UNIX OS|Formula| y=kx+j |Severity| Critical|
```

I added an echo after the command, so that the command prompt will be on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that shell matters here. Do you have cat, awk and sed utilities? You can do this, for example:

```
cat DATA | awk 'BEGIN {s=""} {s=s$0} END {print s}' | sed 's/ *//g'
```